# Charts.js in Angular 7 - working with imported time for timeseries

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, chart.js

Recently I was working with Angular 7 and Typescript and I'm trying to create webpage that shows some charts for measurement data i'm loading. Measurement object that my program receives has two arrays: value(number) and time(Date object). Their sizes go from 1000 (1000 values and 1000 timestamps). 
Now i can plot my data when X axis shows labels only (zooming or panning the X axis isn't working then).
I have looked at the samples and couldn't really understand how i can add my time array as ticks dataset.

**Here's my code for creating the chart below:**

```
  createPowerChart() {
this.PowerChart = new Chart('powerChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: this.powerchartMeasurementsY,
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderColor: "black",
      borderWidth: 2,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem) {
          return tooltipItem.yLabel;
        }
      }
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: "Power",
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        distribution: "series",
        ticks: {
          source: this.powerchartMeasurementsX
        }
      }]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: false,
    animation: {
      duration: 10
    },
  }
});
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to xy plot your data? because the line chart only takes 1 axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did it after checking some more examples, so if anyone is facing similar issues this could help.
In my code above there's an error where i didn't insert "labels" which are needed to produce X axis in this case. Doing this with

```
ticks: {
          source: this.powerchartMeasurementsX
        }
```

seems to be wrong and the documentation or samples don't really explain how things should be used (or they do but in an advanced way). Anyway this is my code for chart which has zoom and pan, includes time series and sets start and end time for the series. If anyone has questions feel free to ask.

```
this.PowerChart = new Chart('powerChart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.powerchartMeasurementsX,
        datasets: [{
          data: this.powerchartMeasurementsY,
          fill: false,
          lineTension: 0.2,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 2,
        }]
      },
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem) {
              return tooltipItem.yLabel;
            }
          }
        },
        elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 0
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: "Power",
          display: true
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }],
          xAxes:[ {
            type: 'time',
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Time',
            },
            time: {
              unit:'minute',
              unitStepSize:1,
              min: this.powerchartMeasurementsX[0],
              max: this.powerchartMeasurementsX[this.powerchartMeasurementsX.length - 1]
            }
          }
          ]},
          animation: {
          duration: 10
        },
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
          limits: {
            max: 10000,
            min: 1,
          }
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
          limits:
          {
            max: 10000,
            min: 1
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```